# Deleteing millions of files from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to delete 64 million objects from a bucket, leaving about the same number of objects untouched. I have created an inventory of the bucket and used that to create a filtered inventory that has only the objects that need to be deleted.

I created a Lambda function that uses NodeJS to 'async' delete the objects that are fed to it.

I have created smaller inventories (10s, 100s and 1000s of objects) from the filtered one, and used S3 Batch Operation jobs to process these, and those all seem to check out: the expected files were deleted, and all other files remained.

Now, my questions:

- Am I doing this right? Is this the preferred method to delete millions of files, or did my Googling misfire?
- Is it advised to just create on big batch job and let that run, or is it better to break it up in chunks of, say, a million objects?
- How long will this take (approx. of course)? Will S3 Batch go through the list and do each file sequentially? Or does it automagically scale out and do a whole bunch in parallel?
- What am I forgetting?

Any suggestions, thoughts or criticisms are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Wasn't s3 lifecycle policy not an option?

Comment: No, since the 'remaining' files would also be affected by a time limited lifecycle. I thought about adding tags and associate a lifecycle with that, but that would basically be the above situation with 'add tag' instead of 'delete object'. This is a legacy bucket, where the items were not categorised in any way.

Comment: See [Using S3 Batch at Scale](https://d1.awsstatic.com/events/Summits/reinvent2022/STG323_Using-S3-Batch-Operations-to-manage-S3-buckets-at-scale.pdf) including Best Practices at slide 25. Break up large batch jobs into a few smaller ones for highest performance.

Comment: The "large" in this case refers to hundreds of millions or billions of keys. Small jobs (under ~10k keys) may not run as efficiently.

Comment: In addition to the lifecycle policy you could use the CDK or Pulumi.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look into [Stepfunctions Distributed Map feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-orchestrate-large-scale-parallel-workloads.html). I do not know your specific use case but it could help to get the proper scaling.

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/step-functions-distributed-map-a-serverless-solution-for-large-scale-parallel-data-processing/) is a short blog entry how you can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea.
You can provision an EMR cluster, then submit a bash script for deleting S3 files to run on that EMR cluster.
For example:

```
aws s3 rm --recursive s3://bucketname/folderpath --exclude \"doc-prefix*\" --include \"*.pdf\"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).